# Couldn't find Bookmark without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a feature on my social bookmark app where the user can click on a like button under a bookmark url to store that bookmark in their "likes" database.  This is the error I am getting when I click on like in my browser (with the error being thrown at the line `@bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])`:

```
Couldn't find Bookmark without an ID

class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
     like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

     authorize like

app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

Here is my likes controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
     like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

     authorize like

     if like.save
       flash[:notice] = "Liked bookmark"
       redirect_to [@bookmark.topic, @bookmark]
     else
       flash[:error] = "Unable to add like. Please try again."
      redirect_to [@bookmark.topic, @bookmark]
     end
  end
  def destroy
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
      like = current_user.likes.find(params[:id])

      authorize like

      if like.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Removed like."
        redirect_to [@bookmark.topic, @bookmark]
      else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to remove like. Please try again."
        redirect_to [@bookmark.topic, @bookmark]
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my bookmarks controller:

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    bookmark = Bookmark.where(url: params[:bookmark][:url]).first

    @bookmark = bookmark.present? ? bookmark : Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      @bookmark.users << current_user
      Rails.logger.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>> Bookmark: #{@bookmark.inspect}"

      topic_names = params[:topic_names].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')

        @bookmark.topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bookmark
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bookmark_params
      params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url)
    end
end
```

Here is my incoming (topics and bookmark) controller

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    bookmark = Bookmark.where(url: params[:bookmark][:url]).first

    @bookmark = bookmark.present? ? bookmark : Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      @bookmark.users << current_user
      Rails.logger.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>> Bookmark: #{@bookmark.inspect}"

      topic_names = params[:topic_names].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')

        @bookmark.topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bookmark
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bookmark_params
      params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url)
    end
end
```

Here is my user bookmarks controller:

```
class UserBookmarksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks
    @liked_bookmarks = current_user.likes.collect(&:bookmark)
    @liked_topics = @liked_bookmarks.collect(&:topic).uniq
  end
end
```

Any insight you can give to help me solve this error will be much appreciated.  Please let me know if you need to see any other files.

Edit update: Adding requested files:

Here is my topic index view file, which is where I am trying to click the like button:

```
<h1>All Bookmarks</h1>

    <ul class="topics">
        <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
          <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
          <ul class="bookmarks">
            <%= render topic.bookmarks %>
          </ul>    
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br>
```

And here is the partial that is being rendered in the above view:

```
<li><%= bookmark.url %></li>
 <div class="like">        
      <% if show_remove_button %>     
          <%= link_to "Remove", user_bookmark_path(get_user_bookmark_for(bookmark)), method: :delete %>
      <% else %>    
        <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
          <%= link_to [bookmark, like], method: :delete do %><u>Unlike</u><% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to [Like.new], method: :post do %><u>Like</u><% end %>
       <% end %> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the view (at least the part where you create the link or button), it seems that you're not passing the business_id

Comment: Note that the `routes.rb` file is also potentially relevant to these types of errors. If your routes aren't defined in such a way as to provide the URL param as you expect it, `params[:whatever_id]` will be `nil` even if you provide the object in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're not passing in the bookmark_id, please try:

```
<%= link_to [bookmark, Like.new], method: :post do %><u>Like</u><% end %>
```